# Trying to get a SOQL query with no duplicates

Tags: soql, relationships, list

EDIT:
Is there a way where I could just loop through my list and remove the duplicates? It should be easy but I've been having trouble with it.

I have tried a bunch of different methods of getting rid of the duplicates out of the query. The problem is that it is related field  where it's close to something like Contact__r.LastName. Here is my current code:

```
List<Object> names = new List<object>();

public List<Object__c> getNames(){
    if(names==null){
        results = [select Contact__r.LastName FROM OBJECT WHERE Field = True];
        new Set<Object> mySet = new Set<Object>();
        mySet.addAll(results);
        names.addAll(mySet);

    }
    return names;
}  //added so code could be formatted into code block
```

it is no longer giving me an error message but is still giving me duplicates.

Any suggestions on better ways to dedupe or why this solution isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where are the types of results, mySet ?  Is mySet initialized to an empty set before you do addAll(); names also must be initialized to an empty list before doing addAll()

Comment: Ok there was a small problem there but I fixed that and now there's no error message but there are still duplicates. I updated my code above to show my changes

Comment: I'm not sure this actually the answer to your question - but the null object would be because no results are found.  Instead, pull the results into a List and check for the size of the list to determine if action is needed (or simply iterate through)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that before but I know there are results found especially as it is working now but just giving tons of repeats. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to be generic or just excluding the name of your object? Your method has Object__c then the other references are to Object

Comment: I'm just excluding the name of my object

Comment: this code will not compile.  Check your example. This is wrong: `new Set<Object> mySet = new Set<Object>();`

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate? Two records with the same last name? Since you've said in previous comments you want a list of objects rather than string returned, how do you determine which of the two (ore more) records to keep if a duplicate last name is found?

Answer (score 2):

After you check if names equals null you need to instantiate List like this:

```
if ( names == null ) {
    names = new List<Object__c>();
    // here goes the rest of the code
}
```

Because when you try to add all elements of mySet to names if names is null it will throw this error.
Did you try to see in debug log what line of code is throwing this error?

Comment: That is being done, but before a recent edit, the init code wasn't in the code block.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the problem. I have tried to instantiate in several different places just in case but it does not change the results

Comment: I saw it, then he needs to check if it has elements, because it's never null if it's instantiated. instead of if (names == null) he needs to have something like this: if ( names.isEmpty())

Comment: It would really help if you could say what line of code is throwing this error.

Comment: When I try using isEmpty the error is on that line, saying the same thing: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Answer (score 1):

Do you only want to do the query the first time through?  If so, you probably want

```
if(names.isEmpty()){
```

instead of

```
if(names==null){
```

when I run the following code in Execute Anonymous in the Developer Console, I do see the debug message.

```
List<attendance__c> names = new List<attendance__c>();
if(names!=null){
system.debug('names is not null on init');
}
```

Your current query code runs every time that getNames is called

Comment: I think I just want to query the first time. However, I just tried your suggestion and got back another error saying that it's trying to de-reference  null object

Comment: My third block of code works fine in "Execute Anonymous" with this swapped in for line 2 = "    if(names.isEmpty()){".  Are you certain there's no typos in your version?

Comment: When I use your third suggestion (names!=null) I get an empty list returned because the names list starts out as empty

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the problem.  I'm not sure if the code you are talking about is using "names.isEmpty()" or something else.  You can edit your question to include the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a list of objects or a list of strings?

```
public List<String> getNames()
{
  Set<String> nameSet = new Set<String>();
  for (Object obj: [SELECT Contact__r.LastName FROM OBJECT WHERE Field = True])
  {
    nameSet.add(obj.Contact__r.LastName);
  }

  return new List<String>().addAll(nameSet);
}
```

Comment: I need a list of objects

Comment: @user3858610 Ok, can you explain to me what you consider a duplicate then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the unique set of related contacts, then you can use a semi-join, e.g.

```
[select LastName FROM contact WHERE id in (select contact__c from OBJECT where Field = True)];
```